# Posting data to MySql Database through RestApi from Ionic

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, ionic-framework

So I have a form in my ionic app that the user inputs some info and posts it to the database when they hit the submit button. I stringify the object into a json object and then send it through my rest api to my database. The problem I am facing is that when my json string reaches my rest api it does not know how to decode it properly and throws me multiple errors such as unexpected token < and http failure during parsing. I checked the rest api output and it appears that it is having an issue trying to get the property. I have tested it through chrome poster and it seems my issue is that when ionic creates the json string it does not add double quotes around the parameter names. So instead of my json looking like this with the quotations around the key itself.

```
{"id": null,"title":"Testing Rest","message":"Fire reported at (site) (where) at (time) \u2013 evacuate to parking Lot evacuation points",
"severityLevel":"1","description":"There is a fire in the mens bathroom next to Chrome nightclub","scheduleAt":"2017-12-12 05:50:00",
"updatedAt":"2017-12-12 17:50","latitude":"33.28130","longitude":"-111.97324"}
```

It looks like this without the quotations.

```
{id: null,title:"Testing Rest",message:"Fire reported at (site) (where) at (time) \u2013 evacuate to parking Lot evacuation points",
severityLevel:"1",description:"There is a fire in the mens bathroom next to Chrome nightclub",scheduleAt:"2017-12-12 05:50:00",
updatedAt:"2017-12-12 17:50",latitude:"33.28130",longitude:"-111.97324"}
```

So when I test it through Chrome Poster the api accepts the first one with the quotations but it does not accept the one without it. I assume that it must be something in my api that is not accepting it but I do not know how to approach fixing such.

My Rest Api - Create Function

```
 // create alert
    function create(){

        // query to insert record
        $query = "INSERT INTO
                " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                    title=:title, message=:message, severityLevel=:severityLevel, description=:description, scheduleAt=:scheduleAt, 
                    updatedAt=:updatedAt, latitude=:latitude, longitude=:longitude";

        // prepare query
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->title=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->title));
        $this->message=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->message));
        $this->severityLevel=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->severityLevel));
        $this->description=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->description));
        $this->scheduleAt=$this->scheduleAt;
        $this->updatedAt=$this->updatedAt;
        $this->latitude=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->latitude));
        $this->longitude=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->longitude));

        // bind values
        $stmt->bindParam(":title", $this->title);
        $stmt->bindParam(":message", $this->message);
        $stmt->bindParam(":severityLevel", $this->severityLevel);
        $stmt->bindParam(":description", $this->description);
        $stmt->bindParam(":scheduleAt", $this->scheduleAt);
        $stmt->bindParam(":updatedAt", $this->updatedAt);
        $stmt->bindParam(":latitude", $this->latitude);
        $stmt->bindParam(":longitude", $this->longitude);

        // execute query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }
```

Rest Api create.php

```
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// get database connection
include_once '../config/database.php';

// instantiate alert object
include_once '../objects/alert.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

$alert = new Alert($db);

// get posted data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set alert property values
$alert->title = $data->title;
$alert->message = $data->message;
$alert->severityLevel = $data->severityLevel;
$alert->description = $data->description;
$alert->scheduleAt = $data->scheduleAt;
$alert->updatedAt = $data->updatedAt;
$alert->latitude = $data->latitude;
$alert->longitude = $data->longitude;


// create the alert
if($alert->create()){
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Alert was created."';
    echo '}';
}

// if unable to create the alert, tell the user
else{
    echo '{';
        echo '"message": "Unable to create alert."';
    echo '}';
}
?>
```

In Ionic I am stringifying my object like this

```
JSON.stringify(this.alert);
```

And then I am passing this.alert to my provider to send to my api.

```
 newAlert(data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/alerts/create.php?s=' + data)
      .subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I realized I was using a get on the ionic side but I am still facing an issue where the post itself is not calling the url or passing the data.

Comment: `newAlert(data) {
    JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(data);

    let myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    console.log("in new alert prior to promise");
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/alerts/create.php', data, {headers: myheaders})
      .map((response: Response) => {
        console.log("in response");
        console.log(data);
        return response.json();
   
      });
    });
  }`